# Abort trap 6 and text file output

Tags: c, memory-management, fopen, abort

This code is meant to take an input text file, "playlist.txt", which consists of some number of song names, each on its own line. It then shuffles the playlist 7 times and outputs the shuffled lists to out files named "shuffle[day of week]".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void open(char *playlist, int *size);
void shuffle(char *playlist, int size, char *day);

int main()
{
    char playlist[5000];
    int size = 0;
    open(playlist, &size);
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Monday");
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Tuesday");
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Wednesday");
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Thursday");
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Friday");
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Saturday");
    shuffle(playlist, size, "Sunday");
}

void open(char *playlist, int *size)
{
    FILE *in = fopen("playlist.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(&playlist[i], 30, in) != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        (*size)++;
    }
    fclose(in);
}

void shuffle(char *playlist, int size, char *day)
{
    printf("started %s shuffle\n", day);
    int done = 0;
    int n, i, j;
    int tempsize = size;
    char templist[5000];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        strcpy(&templist[i], &playlist[i]);
    }
    char newlist [5000];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        n = rand()%tempsize;
        strcpy(&newlist[i], &templist[n]);
        for(j = n; j < tempsize; j++)
        {
            strcpy(&templist[j], &templist[j+1]);
        }
        tempsize--;
    }
    char listname[20] = "shuffle";
    strcat(listname, day);
    strcat(listname, ".txt");
    FILE *out = fopen(listname, "w");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fprintf(out, "%s\n", &newlist[i]);
    }
    fclose(out);
    printf("Finished %s shuffle\n", day);
}
```

When I run it, the output says that both Monday and Tuesday and started and finished. It then says wednesday started, but then I get Abort trap 6.
Only the output files for monday and tuesday are created, but they both contain seemingly random characters with random numbers of newlines in between them.

What am I doing incorrectly? 
How to I fix the abort trap?

Comment: First, you should always check the return value from `fopen`. It will return NULL if the file can't be opened. Second, you should use a debugger to step through the `while(fgets...` loop while watching what happens to the `playlist` array. That should make the problem obvious (or at least one of the problems).

Comment: regarding this line: void open(char *playlist, int *size);  'open' is a library function name.  And the code does a #include <stdio.h> which has the prototype for open().  So the compiler should have given a warning about mismatched function signatures and the linker may have given a warning about multiple functions of the same name in the same compiled object.

Comment: the file name;: shuffle + wednesday + .txt + null byte is 21 bytes and only 20 bytes are allocated, so the file name buffer is overrun. leading to undefined behaviour and possibly a seg fault event

Comment: the list (of characters) that is the playlist, is being split by a random number those limits are the total length of the list-1 and 0.  This results in a random split of the string of play list names, INCLUDING in the middle of a play list name.  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the error identified by user3629249 (one byte overrun in filename due to Wednesday), the datatype you are using for playlist and templist are incorrect.  If you want a playlist of 5000 songs, each of which is identified by a string of text, you need

```
char *playlist[5000];  /* an 5000-element array of char *s.  */
char *templist[5000];  /* ditto */
```

As you have it, &playlist[i] is the i'th character, of a 5000-element character array, not the i'th string pointer of a 5000-element array of char *s.  In your current implementation, you keep stepping on your data byte by byte as you iterate.  If you change to a char * array, you will step pointer by pointer.

But!  Be advised that you declare a fixed-sized array (5000 elements) but nowhere do you validate that you don't attempt to write more than 5000 elements, which can also lead to either an Abort (signal 6) or a Segfault (signal 9).